# what does the "none" suffix mean?

Tags: linux, fedora

Tried to Google but couldn't find answers, I'm using fedora 20, in my rsyslog.conf , found this line

**"*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages "**

What does "mail.none" and "cron.none" really mean?

I got Linux Bible text book, but this is not explained in details

I apologies for any bad text formatting, my first time posting something here.

Comment: flagged to migrate to [unix.SE] as it's about configuring a UNIX-specific daemon rather than programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages "
```

This statement causes rsyslogd to log all messages that come with the `info` priority to the file `/var/log/messages`. But any message coming either with `mail` or `authpriv` or `cron` facility will not be stored.

Comment: What is not clear and why downvote??

Comment: honestly, i have no idea how to rate your answers, but what i did, i clicked the arrow that's pointing upward .... Your answer is great, both you and @Michael Foukarakis

Answer (score 0):

The selectors:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none
```

match all facilities (`*`) with priority levels `info` and higher, and no priority (`.none`) of the facilities `mail`, `authpriv`, and `cron`.

Check out the rsyslog configuration [documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html#selectors) for more detail on how selectors are formed.